# salary incrment of each year from date but some date(year) are not in database

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on php mysql HR application and i have a table with some field like date and salary and incremented salary as shown the below screenshot. 
 i want a list of a record of each year but some year(date) not in a data base how to get that year as shown in 2nd screenshot
Thanks..
[image: salaryincrmentproblumn]

Comment: Have you some query code that you have been working on, that we might find the errors in - or do you just hope that someone will write this for you?

Comment: Have you tried a solution of your own yet? If so can you show us some code?

Comment: i used only a simply query for geting the year                  SELECT YEAR(effective_date)as year ,old_salary,new_salary, new_salary-old_salary as incrmentedsalary   FROM table but i have no idea how to get the year that is not in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want *that* result.

In the first place, ID = 2 is already in use for the year 2014; assigning 2013 to it is a bad, bad idea. In the second place, it makes no sense to say that the salary for 2013 is 3500, and the increment is 0, when 2013 *isn;'t in the database*.

If 2013 is supposed to have those values, then *put them in the database*.

Otherwise, create a table of years (or a table of integers), and include it in your query with an outer join.

```
create table years (
  yr integer primary key
);

insert into years values
(2012), (2013), (2014), (2015), (2016), 
(2017), (2018), (2019), (2020), (2021);
```

Now you can join those two tables with an outer join. The `coalesce()` expression isn't strictly *necessary* with an outer join, but I think it expresses the result you want.

```
select salaries.id, coalesce(salaries.date, years.yr) as date, 
       salaries.salary, salaries.increment
from years
left join salaries on 
salaries.date = years.yr
where years.yr between 2012 and 2015
order by years.yr;
```

Comment: Mike Sherril Thanks for responding and concept is good!!! Best Luck